# How to keep Heroku NodeJS free live all the time?

Tags: heroku

Heroku sleeps in every half an hour. How to keep it live?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRc52.png)

Comment: I think you'll need to [pay them](https://www.heroku.com/pricing).

Comment: The free plan sleeps after 30 minutes of inactivity, while the "Hobby" plan never sleeps, and it's $7 a month

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroky hobby is $7 per month, it never sleeps.

https://www.heroku.com/pricing